# Combine results of 2 jQuery ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm scratching my head how to combine results of 2 jQuery ajax calls which return the results into the same DOM element. Here is my setup:

- there are 2 calls: one from a list of foods and second from a list of ingredients
- both calls return a list of ingredients
- the idea is to make a shopping list (ingredients to buy) based on 2 sources (list of foods and list of ingredients)
- user can create shopping list either by selecting foods (ingredients are retrieved from the database) or he can select ingredients directly from a list of ingredients

**Problem:** these 2 calls are working fine each on its own. But the problem is that result from one call is always replacing the result from the second call and vice-versa.

```
var postUrl = "http://localhost:8000/ingredients/";
var ingrUrl = "http://localhost:8000/ingrs/";
var selectedFoods = [];
var selectedIngrs = [];


$('.foods a').click(function(event){
    clickedLink = $(this).attr('id');

    if (selectedFoods.indexOf(clickedLink) != -1) {
        var index = selectedFoods.indexOf(clickedLink);
        selectedFoods.splice(index, 1);}   
    else {
        selectedFoods.push(clickedLink);
    };

    var jsonFoods = JSON.stringify(selectedFoods);
    $.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonFoods,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('.ingredients').html(result);
            }
    });       
});


$('.ingr-list a').click(function(event) {
    clickedIngr = $(this).attr('id');


    if (selectedIngrs.indexOf(clickedIngr) != -1) {
        var index = selectedIngrs.indexOf(clickedIngr);
        selectedIngrs.splice(index, 1);}   
    else {
        selectedIngrs.push(clickedIngr);
    };

    var jsonIngrs = JSON.stringify(selectedIngrs);
    $.ajax({
        url: ingrUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonIngrs,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('.ingredients').html(result);
            }
    });

});
```

I tried to play around with this line `$('.ingredients').html(result);` using `append` instead of `html` but that won't work because the user should be able to take ingredients off the list (see the if conditions in both functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use different containers for them

```
<div class="ingredients">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></diV>
</div>
```

Then set the `.html()` of `$("#first")` and `$("#second")` instead of `.ingredients`

Comment: @Esailija I considered that but I need to be able to sort the final list as one single list. I thought that having ingredients in 2 different containers would complicate the sorting, wouldn't it?

Comment: @finspin For sorting you could just detach them from the containers, sort them, and place them back to ingredients container. When are you doing the sorting anyway?

Comment: @Esailija I'm currently doing sorting when I retrieve the ingredients from the database (at http://localhost:8000/ingredients/ and http://localhost:8000/ingrs/). So the ajax response is an html list that is already sorted.

Comment: @finspin Right, this won't have any effect on the sorting done in database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
 $('.ingredients').append(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this is the answer [underscore js template](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

what you need to do is not passing html back, but passing **json** back, and using js template to render it at the browser.

some fake code:

```
var global_ingredients = [];
var list = "<% _.each(ingredients, function(ingredient) \
           { %> <li><%= ingredient.name %></li> <% }); %>;";

$.post('', postdata, function(ingredients){
    global_ingredients.push(ingredients); 
    // here you could also eliminate duplicated ingredients, 
    // sort the ingredients, do whatever you likes
    var new_html = _.template(list,  global_ingredients); 
    $('.ingredients').html(new_html);
});
```